# scraping article with scrapy but results null

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I try to scrape all articles in a website to get the full text, date and also title.
I am using xpath to capture the information I need. I try to be very careful in writing the xpath, but when I run my code it results nothing.

The error message:

```
    result = xpathev(query, namespaces=nsp,
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1582, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

As what I understand, the message means something wrong with the xpath.

Here is the code I have created:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class barchart(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'barchart'
    start_urls = ['https://www.barchart.com/news/commodities/energy']
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//*[@class="stories-list"]//*[@class=["story clearfix "]/a/@href'):
            yield response.follow(
                url=link.get(),
                callback=self.parse_item
            )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'date': response.xpath('//*[@class="field__item"]/time/text()').extract(),
            'title': response.xpath('//*[@class="article-header-wrapper"]//h1//text()').get(),
            'text':''.join([x.get().strip() for x in response.xpath('//*[@class="article-content ng-binding ng-scope"]//p//text()')])
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(barchart)
    process.start()
```

How should I write the xpath in order to capture all the information I need for this web scrapping?

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: it would help to show which line of your code the error comes from

Comment: I am guessing maybe this one? `//*[@class="stories-list"]//*[@class=["story clearfix "]/a/@href` ...I am not xpath expert but the `//*[@class=["story clearfix "]` part doesn't seem right - should that be `//*[@class="story clearfix"]`?

Comment: I directly copied the class name from Elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some minor changes to your initial xpath expression I was able to get the all of the links from the first page okay, However it seems that the inner articles themselves are rendered differently, possibly using angular, so for those I ended up using the scrapy-selenium extension.

With this configuration I was able to get the results.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

class barchart(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'barchart'
    start_urls = ['https://www.barchart.com/news/commodities/energy']
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 10,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME' : "chrome",
        'SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH' : "chromedriver.exe",
        'SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS' : [],
        "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES" : {
            'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
        }
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        sections = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"story clearfix ")]')
        for section in sections:
            link = section.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"story-link")]/@href').get()
            yield SeleniumRequest(url=link, callback=self.parse_item, wait_time=10)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = {
            'date': response.xpath('//div[@class="article-meta"]/span[contains(@class,"article-published")]/text()').get().strip(),
            'title': response.xpath('//h1[contains(@class,"article-title")]/text()').get().strip(),
            'text':''.join([x.get().strip() for x in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"article-content")]//p/text()')])
        }
        yield item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(barchart)
    process.start()
```

Comment: Hi alex, thankyou for your help. I tried to run this with pycharm and I got an error: ```'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.``` should I download the chromedriver first and put into my scrapy spider folder?

Comment: yes you would need to download `Chromedriver` and set the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @nomnomyang  Yes, When I ran it I had chromedriver in my CWD... really all you need is to change  SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH to the path of the chromedriver

Comment: I have downloaded the chromedriver by using ```brew install --cask chromedriver
``` and it was success and saves to ```'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver```. I put the path into the ```SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH```, but when I try to run and save the output to csv by using ```scrapy crawl barchart -O barchart.csv``` it still doesnt work, it says ```“chromedriver” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified```. What should I do to fix this? @alexdev

Comment: @nomnomyang  I wish I knew.  I have no experience working on a mac.  Since you are using the scrapy CLI  you could move everything in `custom_settings` to your settings.py file, but that is a longshot... Perhaps you need admin priveleges... I honestly don't know

Comment: On macOS, you will need to open `chromedriver` executable from finder. You will see the warning. Accept the warning to run it. You need to do it once. Now you can close the running driver and your code would be able to run `chromedriver`.